How are bivectors generally multiplied?
I'm studying geometric algebra (mostly from Lasenby). I have some issues in understanding how higher grade elements multiply together. I'm referring to 3D only for now.

Take two bivectors A and B. These can be defined as a^a' and b^b' where each letter is a vector.
What is the geometric product AB? Do I use the identity a^a' = Iā (where ā is the vector perpendicular to the bivector), so we get
IāIb = -āb = - (ā dot b + ā ^ b)?

What if the two bivectors lie in the same plane? That would mean ā dot b is one, while the antisymmetric part is zero. My issue here is that the defining vectors, a,a',b and b' can in principle be all different vectors (albeit lying in the same plane). Can the geometric product distinguish between two such bivectors, say when the angle aa' = bb'=90° and ab = a'b = ab' = 45° (think of two squares with a relative rotation of 45°)?

What is the dot product of two bivectors? I've seen this definition


(a^a') dot (b^b') = (a dot b')(a' dot b) - (a dot b)(a' dot b')
But I don't understand how this is derived.
Thank you all!
PS: sorry for the formatting, on my phone

"sorry for the formatting, on my phone" Are you going to clean this up?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@KurtG. As soon as I get back from work

$
\newcommand\grade{\mathrm{gr}}
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin\lfloor}
$(1) There are many ways you could calculate this, and what's best depends on what you want to accomplish. What you've done is valid (assuming you meant to use $\bar b$ in your last equation). One alternative is simply $AB = A\cdot B + A\times B$ where $A\times B = \frac12(AB - BA)$ is the commutator product; $A\cdot B$ is the scalar part and $A\times B$ is the bivector part.
(2) $A$ and $B$ lie in the same plane iff $A = \alpha B$ for some nonzero scalar $\alpha$.
(3) In Doran and Lasenby's notation $$A\cdot B = A*B = \langle AB\rangle$$ whenever $A, B$ have the same grade. Let $\grade(A)$ denote the grade of a homogeneous multivector $A$. In general if $A$ and $B$ are homogeneous multivectors then they define $$A\cdot B = \langle AB\rangle_{|\grade(A)-\grade(B)|}$$ and then extend by linearity to arbitrary multivectors. If $A, B, C$ are homogeneous multivectors with $\grade(A)+\grade(B) \leq \grade(C)$ then $$(A\wedge B)\cdot C = A\cdot(B\cdot C),$$ and if $B, C$ are arbitrary non-scalar homogeneous multivectors and $a$ is a vector then $$a\cdot(B\wedge C) = (a\cdot B)\wedge C + \hat B\wedge(a\cdot C).$$ These facts allow you to calculate $A\cdot B$ when $A, B$ are bivectors:
$$\begin{aligned}
  A\cdot B
  &= (a\wedge a')\cdot(b\wedge b')
\\&= a\cdot[a'\cdot(b\wedge b')]
\\&= a\cdot[(a'\cdot b)b' - b(a'\cdot b')]
\\&= (a'\cdot b)(a\cdot b') - (a\cdot b)(a'\cdot b').
\end{aligned}$$
The above rules are quite annoying. That's why the following definitions are commonly used instead. First, for any multivector $A$ define $\langle A\rangle_k = 0$ if $k < 0$. Then for homogeneous $A, B$ define $$A\lcontr B = \langle AB\rangle_{\grade(B)-\grade(A)}$$ and extend by linearity to all multivectors to define the left contraction. Then all restrictions are lifted: for arbitrary not-necessarily homogeneous $A, B, C$ we have $$(A\wedge B)\lcontr C = A\lcontr(B\lcontr C)$$ and for any vector $a$ we have $$a\lcontr(B\wedge C) = (a\lcontr B)\wedge C + \hat B\wedge(a\lcontr C).$$ We can similarly define a right contraction
$$
  A\rcontr B = \langle AB\rangle_{\grade(A) - \grade(B)}
$$
with analogous properties as suggested by the notation.

Thank you so much!
